# I'm having a hard time making an element fixed and staying in it's current position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element that needs to stay fixed in its last known position until certain conditions are met.

Originally this element is static until I scroll past a certain point, then it becomes fixed up until a certain point, at this point I want it to stay where it is until I scroll back up again.

Right now I have all of these triggers in place, but I just can't get the element to stay fixed to its last known location.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
        var imgCon = $('#imageContent');
        var txtCon = $('#textContent');
        var offset = txtCon.offset();
        var txtCon = offset.top - 60;
        var el = document.getElementById('imageContent');
        var loc = dw_getPageOffsets(el);
        var el2 = document.getElementById('textContent');
        var loc2 = dw_getPageOffsets(el2);
        var locy = loc.y + $('#firstImage').height();
        var locyb = loc2.y + $('#textContent').height();
        var contentWth = $('#postContent').width();
        var number = contentWth * 0.35;
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= txtCon && locy <= locyb && $(this).scrollTop() + $('#firstImage').height() + 60 <= locyb) {
            imgCon.addClass('fixed');
            imgCon.removeClass('floatImage');
            imgCon.css('width',number);
            $(window).resize(_.debounce(function(){
                $('#imageContent').css('width',number);
            },10));
        } else {
            imgCon.removeClass('fixed');
            imgCon.addClass('floatImage');
        }
```

Now if you can work out what I want, great, but I would assume you would prefer a fiddle so [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/CRKfv/6/).

When the bottom **yellow** box reaches level with the bottom of the green box, **I want the red box to stay fixed in its current location**, until I scroll up again and my `scrollTop()` has gone past the top of the yellow and red boxes. When I have scrolled to that point I want it to become fixed and move back up with me again.

As you can see I almost have that behaviour but so far I have been unable to get the red box to stay fixed.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you're up to but that looks like something that can be taken care of by `position:fixed` in CSS.

Comment: Yes, I am using `position:fixed`

Comment: No, I mean, why not _just_ `position:fixed` to begin with?

Comment: @bvukelic Ah, I see, because I don't want it to be `position:fixed;` until I scroll down ~200px. If I have you mistaken, you could try and edit the fiddle I made and show me there?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. You want the red box to start following the green one once you've scrolled down a bit (with a lag, so to speak). If that's the case, you should clarify the question and also remove the yellow box from the fiddle because it's irrelevant.

Comment: @UzumakiDev should i provide a simple fiddle?

Comment: @bvukelic The yellow box is not irrelevant because when the bottom of the yellow box is level with the bottom of the green box is when I want to become `fixed`.

Comment: @Zword Sure :) if you want.

Comment: Well, technically, in your concrete situation it's relevant, but it's not really relevant to demonstrate the technique.

Comment: @UzumakiDev check this http://jsfiddle.net/QTb2H/ .I havent got the complete grap of what you want but hope this will help you.If it doesnt just clarify more briefly

Comment: @UzumakiDev Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CRKfv/7/ EDIT: There are positioning issues, and for some reason the .fixed class doesn't work as expected, but I didn't go too far trying to figure those issues out.

Comment: @Zword Thanks, not quite what I need :) if you can make your box stop and stay in that position after say ~100px, while you continue scrolling. Then un-fix it when you scroll back up and it comes into view again. That is what I want, understand? :)

Comment: Any source which can show us the output u want?

Comment: @Zword have you seen my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/CRKfv/6/ scroll down and when both the red and yellow box disappear, though it was already `fixed` that's when I want it to stay in its current position.

Comment: @UzumakiDev: Ok, I see the positioning problem. It happens because when an element is `position:fixed` it's positioned relative to the viewport and not the container, so you get a discrepancy in the dimensions if you use `%` units. You might want to either make the container the same size as viewport (no margin/padding) or fix the width manually.

Comment: @bvukelic No, I don't think you understand. I already have the scroll after ~200px already, It's just not shown in my fiddle. Look at my fiddle, when you scroll down and both the yellow and red box disappear, though it was already `fixed` that's when I want it to **stay** in those coordinates. So when I scroll back up it will still be in that position.

Comment: @bvukelic in regards to % width and position fixed I already fixed that with:

`var contentWth = $('#postContent').width();
var number = contentWth * 0.35;`

Comment: @UzumakiDev: I'm not sure we're seeing the same behavior in the fiddle then. Here it appears exactly as if the red box is `position:fixed` **at all times**. They don't disappear, they don't stop or move, or anything. They just stay there. EDIT: maybe if you could tell us which browser you are testing in...

Comment: Ok, now I get it. You've set the body height too small, and your problem never showed up for us. Setting it to a larger value like 2000px makes the problem appear.

Comment: @bvukelic I'm in chromium. You see I don't want the red box to be fixed at all times, lets say I want it only to be `fixed` between 200px and 500px else it should be static.

Comment: I don't think you want `static` for this. Let me see if I can figure it out. :)

Comment: @bvukelic Ah yes, I mean it should still be `fixed` but it should stay in the position as though it was `static`. I think you are catching on :)

Comment: If you're learning and you want to create this by yourself - great! If you really don't need to reinvent the wheel, look at this plugin http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Yes! I think this is what I'm looking for, if the fixed top menu is done using the plugin that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Brilliant that was EXACTLY what I wanted, I would have preferred to do it myself but ain't nobody got time fo dat. Thanks again.